# Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml, reason: Failure initializing default SSL context

Tags: android

Launching the android SDK manager from the command line gets me this error and others like:

> Failed to fetch URL
>   http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml, reason:
>   Failure initializing default SSL context

I've done plenty of searches and have forced http instead of https, created an *androidtool.cfg* file and added the line `sdkman.force.http=true`

permisions for all files in *~/.android* are **rw r r**.

I'm calling android logged in as the owner of those files.

I am not using a proxy and I have no anti virus running.

I just installed fedora 16 and am not sure of any firewalls running by default.

I suspect a permissions problem somewhere along the line.

any ideas?

UPDATE:
I removed fedora and am using another distro.
If ever I return to Fedora and have the same issue I'll being the working answer here.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

For Linux Users:

If have added androidtool.cfg in ~/.android , checked all the permissions , tried force http using the UI but nothing seems to work for you. May be this will help you overcome the problem.

type `locate jre` in terminal.

map yourself to your `jdk/jre/bin` folder. For me it is

```
/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/bin
```

Open the android (the executable file)

locate the line

```
java_cmd="java" (should be the 62nd line in the file)
```

replace it with

```
java_cmd="path_to_your_jre_bin/java"
```

for me it is

```
java_cmd="/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/bin/java"
```

Save the file.

And try again.

Hope it helps.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try if I come by the problem again (I ended up dropping Fedora).

Comment: I tested this and it works. Thanks. Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

For my debian I needed to install sun java properly:

```
su
apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts
update-java-alternatives -s java-6-sun
exit
```

After that, I was able to run the update without errors.

Comment: Interesting. All java *something* related solutions. :)

Answer (score 0):

He had an idea see http://blog.erdn.info/?p=7.

```
apt-get remove gcj-4.4-base
```

Comment: Might be right but I ended up removing fedora. If I come across the problem again I'll try the solutions here to confirm/disaffirm. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioning that you were running from the command line gave me the idea to load it via the file system GUI.  Doing that worked fine for me.

Comment: Might be right but I ended up removing fedora. If I come across the problem again I'll try the solutions here to confirm/disaffirm. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

On my debian (unstable/amd64), I had to upgrade openjdk